# Почему не снимаются чекбоксы?

Tags: javascript

JS-скриптом формируются ссылки при активации чекбоксов, человек переходит на страницу, при активации трех чекбоксов, но затем при нажатии в браузере кнопки "назад", чекбоксы на странице остаются активированы, не смотря на то, что указано их обновление при заходе на страницу. Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const obj = {
  a: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  b: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  c: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
}

inputs.forEach(addListener);

function addListener(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
}

function onClickHandler(e) {
  changeObjectValues(obj[e.target.name], e.target.value, true);
  const checkedInputs = getСlosestCheckedInputs(e.target);

  if (checkedInputs.length > 0) uncheckInputs(checkedInputs);

  if (isAllChecked()) {
    const url = 'https://site.ru/' + Object.keys(obj).map(getPath).join('');
    location.href = url;
  }
}

function getPath(key) {
  return obj[key].path;
}

function isAllChecked() {
  return Object.keys(obj).every(isChecked);
}

function isChecked(key) {
  return obj[key].isChecked === true;
}

function changeObjectValues(obj, path, isChecked) {
  obj.path = path;
  obj.isChecked = isChecked;
}

function getСlosestCheckedInputs(target) {
  const inputs = target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const checkedInputs = [];

  inputs.forEach(function getCheckedInput(input) {
    if (input.checked && input != target) checkedInputs.push(input);
  });

  return checkedInputs;
}

function uncheckInputs(checkedInputs) {
  checkedInputs.forEach(function uncheck(input) {
    input.checked = false;
  })
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.form-check-input').prop('checked', false);
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.a>.row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.b>.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.c>.row {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!-- A -->
<div class="a container">
  <div class="row">
    <input class ="form-check-input"  id="a-1" type="checkbox" value="/a-1/" name="a">
    <label for="a-1">a 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input class ="form-check-input" id="a-2" type="checkbox" value="/a-2/" name="a">
    <label for="a-2">a 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- B -->
<div class="b container">
  <div class="row">
    <input class ="form-check-input"  id="b-1" type="radio" value="b-1/" name="b">
    <label for="b-1">b 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input class ="form-check-input"  id="b-2" type="radio" value="b-2/" name="b">
    <label for="b-2">b 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- C -->
<div class="c container">
  <div class="row">
    <input class ="form-check-input"  id="c-1" type="checkbox" value="c-1" name="c">
    <label for="c-1">c 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input class ="form-check-input"  id="c-2" type="checkbox" value="c-2" name="c">
    <label for="c-2">c 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Класс `form-check-input` точно есть на чекбоксах? Вы html код не привели и не очень понятно.

Comment: @Дмытрык поправил

Comment: @Eleferen поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

let obj = {};

window.addEventListener('pageshow', function() {
  uncheckInputs(inputs);
  obj = {
    a: {
      path: '',
      isChecked: false
    },
    b: {
      path: '',
      isChecked: false
    },
    c: {
      path: '',
      isChecked: false
    }
  };
});

inputs.forEach(addListener)
...
...
...
```

Comment: меня почему-то заблокировали на предыдущем аккаунте, бро, извини

Comment: Почему-то не работает, возможно, я неверно объяснил проблему. Необходимо, чтобы при возвращении назад на страницу нажатием кнопки "назад" страница как-бы загружалась заново, с дефолтным состоянием чекбоксов

Comment: `const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

uncheckInputs(inputs);

const obj = {
  a: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  b: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  c: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
}`

Comment: Я понял. Добавь тогда `uncheckInputs(inputs);` после `location.href = url;`

Comment: И надо будет ещё объект к начальным значениям тогда привести.

Comment: или вот так ещё можно сделать `window.onpageshow = function() {
  uncheckInputs(inputs);
};`

Comment: @flyflybird поменял ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо, узнаю причину блокировки на предыдущем аккаунте и обязательно поставлю галку.